# LINQ query for just computed values with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What is the best way to structure a query consisting solely of row counts and existence checks? Here is what I do currently:

```cs
var fruitSummary = (
    from _ in db.Apples
    select new {
        GreenAppleCount = db.Apples.Count(a => a.Color == "Green"),
        Yuck = db.Bananas.Any(b => b.Age > 10)
    }).First();
```

This construct meets my primary goal of making a single call to the database, but it seems there should be a cleaner way to express it. Notice in the `from` clause that `_ in db.Apples` is unused. It could have been `_ in db.Wildebeests`, and the same query would have resulted. Is there a way to avoid the unused table reference?

Answer (score 0):

The most "sensible" option that comes to mind is to create a stored procedure that computes both values that is called from EF.  This can be an option any time you wish to "do multiple things" in a single DB round trip.

Comment: That would work. Unfortunately, it is incompatible with many of LINQ's features, such as compile-time type checking, refactoring, and IDE navigation. Plus you need to write and deploy the stored procedure, which is a hassle if you're using EF Code First.

Answer (score -1):

Best way of writing about query is

```
     var output = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(o => 
              new {
                 GreenAppleCount = db.Apples.Count(a => a.Color == "Green"),
                 Yuck = db.Bananas.Any(b => b.Age > 10
                  });
```

Comment: This fails to meet the primary goal of performing only one DB query, unlike the OP's code.

Comment: my answer is all about writing your code in optimized way. iteration of your query depends upon number of rows in table Apples, if apples contain 1000 rows your code will get executed 1000 times. There is no way to give single hit to DB until and unless apples and bananas have relations.

Comment: 1) It's not my question 2) This is in no way optimized, in fact, it is dramatically *worse* than the code in the question as this performs two separate round trips to the DB, rather than just one.

Comment: @slash To clear up a misconception, the query in the question makes a single database call regardless of the relationship between Apples and Bananas. Even if the tables are completely unrelated, the LINQ query is transformed into a single SELECT statement that get passed to the database in a single call.